# Uppercase string for all UINavigation bar titles

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiappearance

Currently, I am changing the font of the navigation bar using the following in the `AppDelegate`:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  [UIFont fontWithName:@"..." size:...], NSFontAttributeName,
  nil]];
```

Is there a way to do the same to make sure that the string is capitalized globally?

Comment: Doesn't seem possible, though this is relevant: stackoverflow.com/a/6727489

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to achieve this using NSAttributedString, but instead you can change the title in your base view controller class.
Try this:

```
/// Base class for all view controllers
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {

    private var firstWillAppearOccured = false

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if !firstWillAppearOccured {
            viewWillFirstAppear(animated)
            firstWillAppearOccured = true
        }
    }

    /// Method is called when `viewWillAppear(_:)` is called for the first time
    func viewWillFirstAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        title = title?.uppercased() // Note that title is not available in viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the `UIFont` used by the `UINavigationBar` `appearance` to use caps.

```
extension UIFont {

func getAllCapsFont(with size: CGFloat, andWeight weight: Weight) -> UIFont {
    let fontDescriptor = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: size, weight: weight).fontDescriptor
    
    let upperCaseFeature: [UIFontDescriptor.FeatureKey: Int] = [
        .featureIdentifier: kUpperCaseType,
        .typeIdentifier: kUpperCaseSmallCapsSelector
     ]

    let lowerCaseFeature: [UIFontDescriptor.FeatureKey: Int] = [
        .featureIdentifier: kLowerCaseType,
        .typeIdentifier: kLowerCaseSmallCapsSelector
    ]

    let features = [upperCaseFeature, lowerCaseFeature]
    let additions = fontDescriptor.addingAttributes([.featureSettings: features])
    return UIFont(descriptor: additions, size: size)
}
```

}

Comment: Those are small caps. Any chance to use normal caps?

Answer (score -1):

You can create a base `UIViewController` which hides the original navigationBar and add a new one by yourself.

```
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

UINavigationBar *navigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
UINavigationItem *naviItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] init];
self.titleLabel = [UILabel new];
naviItem.titleView = self.titleLabel;
navigationBar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:naviItem, nil];
[self.view addSubview:navigationBar];
```

Then you can control the setting of title for the titleLabel.